# What is causing the array out of bounds to occur?

Tags: c++, arrays

After the second iteration of "enter number for second: ", the program crashes. I don't see why; it should still be in bounds.

```
int arr1[3];
int arr2[3];
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (i < 4)
    {
        cout << "enter number for first: ";
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "enter number for second: ";
        cin >> arr2[i-4];
    }
}
```

Comment: But you know that arrays are indexed from 0? So if you have array of size 3 then maximum index you can access is 2?

Comment: Arrays in C++ are zero-based. Array of size 3 has the indexes [0,1,2].

Comment: yes...6-4=2. Am I missing something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks even a minimal knowledge of the language used.

Comment: @Celeritas at i == 3, i < 4 so it tries to access arr1[3] which is out of bounds.

Comment: @Celeritas you know you can make two for loops from [0,2] one accepting `arr1` and the other one `arr2` instead of condition, which would make your code much cleaner. Back to the original question. Considering you are trying to cin `arr1` and `arr2` 3 times, you should start your loop from zero and change 4 to 3

Comment: @Gasim I didn't use two for loops b/c I thought it would make the code dirtier. But I think I was mistaking.

Comment: for me, I always go for less indents. plus less operations (this is much simpler: http://ideone.com/0Cblca) :D

Comment: If you are going to iterate over two different arrays then use two `for` loops. It is more natural and easier to get correct. What you have now looks error-prone and harder to reason about its behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i=3, you insert into arr1[3] when the highest index in this array is 2 (three indexes: 0,1,2.

Replace every 4 in your code with 3. It is also better to use constant for this value.

I believe that you have another thing in your code:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
```

This loop runs only 5 iterations, from 1 to 5. As it is now, you never write to the first index of arr1.

Start from i=0.

Comment: "Replace every 4 in your code with 3." doesn't work because then the user is only prompted twice to enter values for the first one

Comment: @Celeritas See my answer - what you wrote is only because you started the loop from index 1 instead of index 0!

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr1[3];
int arr2[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (i < 3)
    {
        cout << "enter number for first: ";
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "enter number for second: ";
        cin >> arr2[i-3];
    }
}
```

Try that since array's start at ZERO,  arr[3]  =  0,1,2

Comment: Don't down vote me and the not say why. I provided a solution and with all the comments above any person could figure out what was wrong.

Comment: loop should start from '0' not '1'

Comment: well you kept the i = 1 so you missed 0 index for arr1

Comment: True that, you should edit your answer... as you're simply ignoring the first element.

Comment: Gasim, ok i didn't see that he did that. Simply copied his amazing code and flipped the 4's

Comment: We need more information from the user to provide a better solution. This implementation is a little awkward IMO.

Comment: @jon_shep yes I did leave out some information from the question which I thought was extraneous but now I see it would have helped find a better implementation. At any rate, these answers gave me the help I needed and I can take it from here thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look how your program will work for each value

first iteration:

- i = 1
- if test is true 1 < 4
- cin to arr1[1]
- note: skipped index arr1[0]

second iteration:

- i = 2
- if test is true 2 < 4
- cin to arr1[2]

third iteration:

- i = 3
- if test is true 3 < 4
- cin to arr1[3] - here is your index out of bound. arrays in C and C++ are zero-based so maximum index for array is size of array - 1

I will stop analysing here because it's your faulty part and you should be fine from now.

Oh also you should start reading a book about C++ because your fail at very begining of your journey will become bigger fail later. You lack knowledge of language basics

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are index from 0, not from 1, as your code seems to assume. Valid positions in `arr1` and `arr2` are thus 0, 1 and 2.

Modify your loop to run from `for(int i=0; i<6; ++i)`, change your loop-condition to look for `i<3`, and then change the indexing of `arr2` to be `i-3` instead.

Your loop will then run as follows:

```
i=0: enter number for first, stored in arr1[0]
i=1: enter number for first, stored in arr1[1]
i=2: enter number for first, stored in arr1[2]
i=3: enter number for second, stored in arr2[0]
i=4: enter number for second, stored in arr2[1]
i=5: enter number for second, stored in arr2[2]
```